# Link to a page in django cms, first check if it exists

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I often do things like this in a django template, with django-cms:

```
{% load cms_tags %}
<a href="{% page_url 'imprint' %}">Imprint</a>
```

On production, this fails silently, and the href attribute is empty. On development, I'm forced to insert the page with id "imprint", otherwise I get a "DoesNotExist" exception.

How can I improve this situation? Maybe I'm looking for something like

```
{% if 'imprint'|cms_page_exists %}
    ...the link and stuff...
```

Is there a known best practice for this (not quite seldom) use case? Or do you all use it as shown first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assign a tag result to a variable and then check is it empty:

```
{% page_url 'imprint' as url %}
{% if url %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">Imprint</a>
{% endif %}
```

Other ways imply creating your own template tag or filters, so the above is the simplest one IMHO.
See also an example in the [docs](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/templatetags.html#page-url).

Comment: silly me. thought it would throw a "DoesNotExist", but does not when using the "as" syntax! thx for trying :)

Comment: am I the only one, or is this no more working in django-cms 3.5+??!